# how to optimized without union clauses?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to write below query without a union clause.

```
select ProductId,ImageName,ImageType, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ProductId desc) RowId 
from
                (
                    select p.id ProductId ,p.pic_image ImageName,'pic_image' ImageType
                    from product p
                    left outer join iimages_edited pe on p.id = pe.[id] 
                    where isnull(p.pic_image,'') <> '' and isnull(pe.pic_image,0)=0 
                    union
                    select p.id ProductId,p.pic_bimage ImageName,'pic_bimage' ImageType
                    from product p 
                    left outer join iimages_edited pe on p.id = pe.[id] 
                    where isnull(p.pic_bimage,'') <> '' and isnull(pe.pic_bimage,0)=0
                    union
                    select p.id ProductId,p.pic_limage ImageName,'pic_limage' ImageType
                    from product p 
                    left outer join iimages_edited pe on p.id = pe.[id] 
                    where isnull(p.pic_limage,'') <> '' and isnull(pe.pic_limage,0)=0 
                    union
                    select p.id ProductId,p.pic_blimage ImageName,'pic_blimage' ImageType
                    from product p 
                    left outer join iimages_edited pe on p.id = pe.[id] 
                    where isnull(p.pic_blimage,'') <> '' and isnull(pe.pic_blimage,0)=0 
                    union
                    select p.id ProductId,p.pic_cimage ImageName,'pic_cimage' ImageType
                    from product p 
                    left outer join iimages_edited pe on p.id = pe.[id] 
                    where isnull(p.pic_cimage,'') <> '' and isnull(pe.pic_cimage,0)=0       
            )t
```

> Above query has same table but different where condition, It is
>   possible to do it in a single query ?

Any help will be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you simplify your query? Just show us the basic problem, right now it's just a wall of sql...

Comment: @jarlh Please check now

Comment: IS it the correct method

Comment: You can re-write it. OR the where clauses together. Have a case in the select-list. Perhaps SELECT DISTINCT is needed.

Comment: @jarlh like this !!


WHERE
   ( ISNULL(p.pic_image,'')     <> '' AND ISNULL(pe.pic_image,    0)=0) 
   OR
   ( ISNULL(p.pic_bimage,'')    <> '' AND ISNULL(pe.pic_bimage,   0)=0)
   OR 
   ( ISNULL(p.pic_limage,'')    <> '' AND ISNULL(pe.pic_limage,   0)=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are repeating the same join and filters with differents columns each time. You can convert them to rows using [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), on each table, before the join :

```
select pe.ProductId, p.ProductId, p.ImageName, p.ImageType, ROW_NUMBER() 
over (order by p.ProductId desc) RowId 
from (
  select id as ProductId, ImageType, ImageName
  from product
  unpivot (
    ImageType for ImageName 
    in (pic_image, pic_bimage, pic_limage, pic_blimage, pic_cimage)
  ) t
) as p
left outer join (
  select id as ProductId, ImageType, ImageName
  from iimages_edited
  unpivot (
    ImageType for ImageName 
    in (pic_image, pic_bimage, pic_limage, pic_blimage, pic_cimage)
  ) t
) as pe
on p.ImageType = pe.ImageType
  and p.ProductId = pe.ProductId
where pe.ProductId is null
```

`UNPIVOT` filters `null` values, so `ISNULL` are probably not necessary.

Comment: This takes dual time than the existing query :(

Comment: Maybe because one large outer join cost more than 5 smaller ones ? I have no idea (beside analyzing the query plan for both queries).